# Compare Select Options

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to compare the values of two select options and present a third value based on the two selected options. I found [this example on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529797/jquery-join-two-form-select-elements-into-one-value-then-change-that-value-using):

But can't seem to get it to work. My own code is below:

```
 $('#forest-size', '#forest-age').change(function() {
          var val =  $('#forest-size').val() + $('#forest-age').val(), 
         initial_crediting;

         switch (val) {

          case "A1" : 
              initial_crediting = "0 - 10";
              break;

          case "A2" : 
              initial_crediting = "0 - 10";
              break;

          case "B1" : 
              initial_crediting = "0 - 8";
              break;

          case "B2" : 
              initial_crediting = "10 - 18";
              break;

          case "B3" : 
              initial_crediting = "18 - 24";
              break;

          case "C1" : 
              initial_crediting = "20 - 30";
              break;

          case "C2" : 
              initial_crediting = "30 - 40";
              break;

          case "C3" : 
              initial_crediting = "40 - 50";
              break;
         }

          $('#results').text(initial_crediting);
      });
      </script>
```

So far, I'm not displaying a value in #results, and yet, I don't see any errors in the console. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below (**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/adqo5ka3/)**):

**HTML Code**

```
<label>Option A</label>
<select id="forest-size">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<br />
<label>Option B</label>
<select id="forest-age">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
Results: <span id="results"></span>
```

**Script**

```
$('#forest-size, #forest-age').change(function() {
   var val = $('#forest-size').val() + $('#forest-age').val();
   var initial_crediting = '';

    switch (val) {
    case "A1":
        initial_crediting = "0 - 10";
        break;
    case "A2":
        initial_crediting = "0 - 10";
        break;
    case "A3":
        initial_crediting = "not specified";
        break;
    case "B1":
        initial_crediting = "0 - 8";
        break;
    case "B2":
        initial_crediting = "10 - 18";
        break;
    case "B3":
        initial_crediting = "18 - 24";
        break;
    case "C1":
        initial_crediting = "20 - 30";
        break;
    case "C2":
        initial_crediting = "30 - 40";
        break;
    case "C3":
        initial_crediting = "40 - 50";
        break;
    default:
        initial_crediting = "please select both options";
    }

    $("#results").text(initial_crediting);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your detailed example, it helped in relationship to Girish's explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#forest-size', '#forest-age')` the selector means `#forest-size` element is child of `#forest-age` element, or better to understand the code work like

```
  $('#forest-age').find('#forest-size')
```

but you want to attach event on both selector so change

```
 $('#forest-size', '#forest-age').change(function() {
```

to

```
$('#forest-size, #forest-age').change(function() {
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it helped in concert with Chandan's example above.